# Re-raise Python exception and preserve stack trace

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace

I'm trying to catch an exception in a thread and re-raise it in the main thread:

```py
import threading
import sys

class FailingThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        try:
            raise ValueError('x')
        except ValueError:
            self.exc_info = sys.exc_info()

failingThread = FailingThread()
failingThread.start()
failingThread.join()

print failingThread.exc_info
raise failingThread.exc_info[1]
```

This basically works and yields the following output:

```
(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError('x',), <traceback object at 0x1004cc320>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise failingThread.exc_info[1]
```

However, the source of the exception points to line 16, where the re-raise occurred. The original exception comes from line 7. How do I have to modify the *main* thread so that the output reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
```

Comment: awesome, I've been re-raising exceptions from other threads too, but never went as far you want to :)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Inner exception" (with traceback) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350671/inner-exception-with-traceback-in-python)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In Python 2 you need to use all three arguments to raise:

```
raise failingThread.exc_info[0], failingThread.exc_info[1], failingThread.exc_info[2]
```

passing the traceback object in as the third argument preserves the stack.

From `help('raise')`:

> If a third object is present and not `None`, it must be a traceback
>   object (see section *The standard type hierarchy*), and it is
>   substituted instead of the current location as the place where the
>   exception occurred.  If the third object is present and not a
>   traceback object or `None`, a `TypeError` exception is raised. The
>   three-expression form of `raise` is useful to re-raise an exception
>   transparently in an except clause, but `raise` with no expressions
>   should be preferred if the exception to be re-raised was the most
>   recently active exception in the current scope.

In this particular case you cannot use the no expression version.

For Python 3 (as per the comments):

```
raise failingThread.exc_info[1].with_traceback(failingThread.exc_info[2])
```

or you can simply chain the exceptions using `raise ... from ...` but that raises a chained exception with the original context attached in the **cause** attribute and that may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @AndyHayden Indeed, in Python 3 [raise](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) would have to be called somehow like `raise failingThread.exc_info[0](failingThread.exc_info[1]).with_traceback(failingThread.exc_info[2])`. Although in Python 3 the `raise AnotherError from stored_exception` might provide an even better output

Comment: correction, the first one should be `raise failingThread.exc_info[1].with_traceback(failingThread.exc_info[2])` as per [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188563/how-to-re-raise-an-exception-in-nested-try-except-blocks/18188660?noredirect=1#comment26654548_18188660)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Would you mind either extrapolating your highly upvoted comments into a new answer *or* editing them into the current answer? In the post-Python 2 era, Python 2-only solutions are sadly obsolete.

Comment: @CecilCurry Good suggestion, I updated my answer. Surely though you have enough privilege you could have just edited it directly?

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet works in both python 2 & 3:

```
      1 try:
----> 2     raise KeyError('Default key error message')
      3 except KeyError as e:
      4     e.args = ('Custom message when get re-raised',) #The comma is not a typo, it's there to indicate that we're replacing the tuple that e.args pointing to with another tuple that contain the custom message.
      5     raise
```

Comment: I can guess why the downvote. This solution is only valid if there wasn't any exception handling. Imagine that upon catching the exception you try to update a status in the db and that fails as well. In that case the exception that will be raised is the last one (db transaction failed) and not the one we initially caught.