# How do I recover an older traceback in python? (eg second to last)

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pdb, traceback

I'm sure you found yourself in this situation, and I suspect there is no way out of this.
Suppose you run some python code that raises an exception, then you want to look into it but accidentally raise **another** exception while doing so. If you try postmortem debugging now, you'll see the traceback of the latter exception. My question is, is the former lost forever?

Example:

```
def my_buggy_function(x):
    y = x + 1
    raise RuntimeError
```

Step 1: I raise an error and I want to debug it

```
my_buggy_function(1)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user/<ipython-input-1-430423eaff77> in <module>()
      3     raise RuntimeError
      4 
----> 5 my_buggy_function(1)

/home/user/<ipython-input-1-430423eaff77> in my_buggy_function(x)
      1 def my_buggy_function(x):
      2     y = x + 1
----> 3     raise RuntimeError
      4 
      5 my_buggy_function(1)

 RuntimeError:
```

Step 2: I try to debug the error but accidentally raise another one (in this case, I did not load pdb)

```
 pdb.pm() #Oops..

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 /home/user/<ipython-input-2-619d77b83f20> in <module>()
 ----> 1 pdb.pm()

 NameError: name 'pdb' is not defined

 import pdb
```

Step 3: Now the traceback gives me the last error, and the second to last is lost.

```
 pdb.traceback.print_last()
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line  2538, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-1-619d77b83f20>", line 1, in <module>
   pdb.pm()
 NameError: name 'pdb' is not defined
```

What if I want to access y in the second-to-last traceback, is it lost forever?

Note: I'm using ipython/ipdb in case it matters

Comment: I believe you might be able to access the *last* traceback via ``sys.last_traceback`` -- Give that a go and let me know. I can't reproduce your scenario exactly as I don't use IPython myself.

Comment: @JamesMills When a new exception occurs, won't `last_traceback` point to that one?

Comment: There is also ``sys.exc_tracback`` (*the current traceback being handled*) -- so the ``sys`` documentation leads me to believe that this *might* work.

Comment: That is exactly the problem: there's lots of ways to access the traceback of the last error, but I do not know any way of accessing the previous one (second to last)

Comment: You can turn on ipython's "Automatic pdb calling" by default. That way, your already exactly where you want to be once an uncaught exception occurs.  You can't "lose" it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[Exception chaining](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) is only available in Python 3. It is not available in the 2.X series.

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414892/1055722

EDIT: Reading more closely, you aren't talking about two *nested* exceptions but about one following another?

In that case you could use `sys.excepthook` to capture and store somewhere the last 10 exceptions (for example) so that you can look at the exception history from pdb.

Comment: Yes my question is about two unrelated exceptions, happening one after the other

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after looking at sys.excepthook I'd say I could use it to implement myself some sort of "exception stack", but I was hoping something along this line was already available..

Comment: Sorry, there is no builtin exception history. You will have to roll your own if you want it.