# python how to know which tag exactly is not closed in xml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an xml, and I validate if it is really a good formatted xml like this:

```
try:
            self.doc=etree.parse(attributesXMLFilePath)
        except IOError:
            error_message = "Error: Couldn't find attribute XML file path {0}".format(attributesXMLFilePath)
            raise XMLFileNotFoundException(error_message)
        except XMLSyntaxError:
            error_message = "The file {0} is not a good XML file, recheck please".format(attributesXMLFilePath)
            raise NotGoodXMLFormatException(error_message)
```

as you see, I am catching the XMLSyntaxError, which is an error from :

`from lxml.etree import XMLSyntaxError`

that works good, but that just told me if the file is not a good xml format. However, i want to ask you guys if there is a way to know which tag is wrong because in my situation when i do this:

```
<name>Marco</name1>
```

i got the error, is there a way to know that `name` tag hasn't been closed yet?

#### Update

after some people give me the idea of line and position,i came up with this code:

```
    class XMLFileNotFoundException(GeneralSpiderException):
        def __init__(self, message):
            super(XMLFileNotFoundException, self).__init__(message, self)

class GeneralSpiderException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, e):
        super(GeneralSpiderException, self).__init__(message+" \nline of Exception = {0}, position of Exception = {1}".format(e.lineno, e.position))
```

and i am still raising the error like this

```
raise XMLFileNotFoundException(error_message)
```

i got this error now

```
    super(GeneralSpiderException, self).__init__(message+" \nline of Exception = {0}, position of Exception = {1}".format(e.lineno, e.position))
exceptions.AttributeError: 'XMLFileNotFoundException' object has no attribute 'lineno'
```

Comment: Is what you really want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414744/python-exception-chaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the details of the error. For instance:

```
try:
    self.doc = etree.parse(attributesXMLFilePath)
except XMLSyntaxError as e:
    error_message = "The file {0} is not correct XML, {1}".format(attributesXMLFilePath, e.msg)
    raise NotGoodXMLFormatException(error_message)
```

Comment: this sounds a good option but i have (as you see) a custom exception, and i tried it do self.lineno inside my custom excpeiont, but got error that lineno is not identified,

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I edited my answer to pass the variable to the custom exception

Comment: so you are telling me that i have to pass the number of line and the position every time i  raise an excpetion right?

Comment: I don't know all that much about custom exceptions to tell you for sure. Initially I thought all you wanted was to get the details of that particular error. Incidentally, your edit is all about `XMLFileNotFoundException`, but I think it should be `NotGoodXMLFormatException`.

Comment: the two exceptions are the same, i am asking about the idea, the general idea, rather than a specific exception

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exactly what you want, but you can get the exact line and column where the error was detected from the exception:

```
import lxml.etree
import StringIO
xml_fragment = "<name>Marco</name1>"
#               12345678901234
try:
    lxml.etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(xml_fragment))
except lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError as exc:
    line, column = exc.position
```

In this example, `line` and `column` will be 1 and 14, which indicates the first character of the closing tag that doesn't have a matching opening tag.

Comment: this sounds a good option but i have (as you see) a custom exception, and i tried it do self.lineno inside my custom excpeiont, but got error that lineno is not identified `class XMLFileNotFoundException(GeneralSpiderException):
    def __init__(self, message):
        print self.lineno
        super(XMLFileNotFoundException, self).__init__(message, self)`

Comment: What is `GeneralSpiderException`? Does that inherit from `XMLSyntaxError`?

Comment: that is another exception for me. you shouldn't care about it, it inherits Exception

Comment: i mean the idea, i did the same print inside the other exception `NotGoodXMLFormatException `

Comment: I'm not sure what your custom exception has to do with the exception raised by `lxml.tree.parse`. Maybe you want to catch the syntax error, use that information to identify the element, and put *that* information in your custom exception?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Please edit your question and add information about where exactly you used `exc.position` (or `exc.lineno`) and what is the error.

Comment: i need to print the line number and the position, but i want to print them from my custom exception. In other words, i don't want to print them when the exception happens, i am thinking for that because (i came from java background) if i print them inside my custom exception, so i can throw many exceptions without need to re write the number of line in each one

Comment: I see. But then, if I understand correctly, you have to pass `exc.position` the same way you are passing `error_message` (or included in `error_message`).

Comment: @PauloAlmeida that is why i am trying exactly to avoid, i would like to not pass it everytime, if that is not posible please tell me

Comment: If I understand your update, you need to pass the `XMLSyntaxError` as an argument when you create your custom exception; where else are you doing to get the information about the syntax error?