# Can't get credentials from Google API for Google Sheets using python; behind company proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use Google Sheets with Python. I went to their quickstart tutorial and have been trying to get it to run for quite some time behind a company proxy. I'm on Windows 7, and I've changed the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables appropriately and have also tried setting them in the command prompt prior to running the code. Code is below and error it spits out is below that:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools


SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret.json'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
credz = store.get()
if not credz or credz.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES)
    credz = tools.run_flow(flow, store) #ERROR ON THIS LINE
```

Error1:

> File
>   "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\socket.py",
>
> line 732, in getaddrinfo
>
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Then it spits out "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"

> File
>
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\httplib2__init__.py",
>
> line 994, in _conn_request
>
> raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host) httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at
>
> accounts.google.com

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414892/5832311) wherein the suggested workaround is to add custom attributes to your exception class, like:

> ```
> class MyError(Exception):
>     def __init__(self, message, cause):
>         super(MyError, self).__init__(message + u', caused by ' + repr(cause))
>         self.cause = cause
>
> try:
>     v = {}['a']
> except KeyError as e:
>     raise MyError('failed', e)
> ```

Sometimes, you might need to [provide credentials](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup) to a proxy server in order to use it. Usually, they are submitted using a base64 hash included in an HTTP header.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the first part of your answer relates to my question; could you please explain?

As for the second part, I believe that's what they used for a previous iteration of the Google API (1 or 2) and I believe the most recent is version 4. Regardless, there's no document detailing what to do I Python in regards to configuring the proxy for Google API that I could find. Thanks though!