# Is it possible to catch an exception from outside code that is already catching it?

Tags: python, error-handling

This is a hard question to phrase, but here's a stripped-down version of the situation. I'm using some library code that accepts a callback. It has its own error-handling, and raises an error if anything goes wrong while executing the callback.

```py
class LibraryException(Exception):
    pass

def library_function(callback, string):
    try:
        # (does other stuff here)
        callback(string)
    except:
        raise LibraryException('The library code hit a problem.')
```

I'm using this code inside an input loop. I know of potential errors that could arise in my callback function, depending on values in the input. If that happens, I'd like to reprompt, after getting helpful feedback from its error message. I imagine it looking something like this:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def my_callback(string):
    raise MyException("Here's some specific info about my code hitting a problem.")

while True:
    something = input('Enter something: ')
    try:
        library_function(my_callback, something)
    except MyException as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

Of course, this doesn't work, because `MyException` will be caught within `library_function`, which will raise its own (much less informative) `Exception` and halt the program.

The obvious thing to do *would* be to validate my input *before* calling `library_function`, but that's a circular problem, because parsing is what I'm using the library code for in the first place. (For the curious, it's [Lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark), but I don't *think* my question is specific enough to Lark to warrant cluttering it with all the specific details.)

One alternative would be to alter my code to catch any error (or at least the type of error the library generates), and directly print the inner error message:

```
def my_callback(string):
    error_str = "Here's some specific info about my code hitting a problem."
    print(error_str)
    raise MyException(error_str)

while True:
    something = input('Enter something: ')
    try:
        library_function(my_callback, something)
    except LibraryException:
        continue
```

But I see two issues with this. One is that I'm throwing a wide net, potentially catching and ignoring errors other than in the scope I'm aiming at. Beyond that, it just seems... inelegant, and unidiomatic, to print the error message, then throw the exception itself into the void. Plus the command line event loop is only for testing; eventually I plan to embed this in a GUI application, and without printed output, I'll still want to access and display the info about what went wrong.

What's the cleanest and most Pythonic way to achieve something like this?

Comment: why not catch the specific exception the library raises?

Comment: @Chase 1) What if the library throws the same type of exception for other reasons too? Or what if there are some situations in which my own code's errors can cause the library to throw a slightly different exception? I don't feel like that's entirely safe or future-proof. 2) I'd still have to directly print my own error info... not that big a deal, but still seems awkward.

Comment: Maybe in your last example change continue to raise MyExeption. Or validate user input without exceptions. For example if there are letters in user input, tell user to not input letters.

Comment: @RocketNikita There wouldn't be much point to raising `MyException` in the outer `try`, without the relevant error info from what's actually going on at the lower level. The input is in a [DSL](http://blog.erezsh.com/how-to-write-a-dsl-in-python-with-lark/) I'm parsing, so validating it isn't as simple as just making sure all its characters are of a certain type, etc.

Comment: I *think* you're out of luck, if the library 'masks' internal exceptions instead of chaining them, I don't think there's a way for you to get the inner exception. how about storing  the information you would use for your exception elsewhere (env var / file)? then read the info from it when you catch the library's generic exception...

Comment: @yurib not necessarily, python itself keeps track of the exception history. The whole "During handling of exception A, exception B happened". That's probably what OP is looking for

Comment: @yurib: See [PEP 3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) and the `__cause__` and `__context__` attributes.

Comment: I'd assume [`traceback.walk_tb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.walk_tb) may be helpful in "unwrapping" the traceback at hand, possibly encountering any previous exceptions that caused the current exception along the way. Though I'd rather test that before I make a statement. For OP's specific example, it works - but whether it is robust or not, needs some testing

Comment: also of note, `traceback.TracebackException(*sys.exc_info()).__context__` in an `except` block, will also give you the direct message from the previous exception. `traceback.format_exc` itself will give you an incredibly convenient string having all the exceptions chained. But to extract the exception chain itself, you'll need to parse it by yourself. Although this is probably the simplest way, perhaps it is not the most ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be many ways to achieve what you want. Though, which one is more robust - I cannot find a clue about. I'll try to explain all the methods that seemed apparent to me. Perhaps you'll find one of them useful.

I'll be using the example code you provided to demonstrate these methods, here's a fresher on how it looks-

```py
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def my_callback(string):
    raise MyException("Here's some specific info about my code hitting a problem.")

def library_function(callback, string):
    try:
        # (does other stuff here)
        callback(string)
    except:
        raise Exception('The library code hit a problem.')
```

### The simplest approach - [`traceback.format_exc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc)

```py
import traceback

try:
    library_function(my_callback, 'boo!')
except:
    # NOTE: Remember to keep the `chain` parameter of `format_exc` set to `True` (default)
    tb_info = traceback.format_exc()
```

This does not require much know-how about exceptions and stack traces themselves, nor does it require you to pass any special frame/traceback/exception to the library function. But look at what this returns (as in, the value of `tb_info`)-

```py
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/test.py", line 14, in library_function
    callback(string)
  File "path/to/test.py", line 9, in my_callback      
    raise MyException("Here's some specific info about my code hitting a problem.")       
MyException: Here's some specific info about my code hitting a problem.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    library_function(my_callback, 'boo!')
  File "path/to/test.py", line 16, in library_function
    raise Exception('The library code hit a problem.')
Exception: The library code hit a problem.
'''
```

That's a string, the same thing you'd see if you just let the exception happen without catching. Notice the exception chaining here, the exception at the top is the exception that happened *prior* to the exception at the bottom. You could parse out all the exception names-

```py
import re
exception_list = re.findall(r'^(\w+): (\w+)', tb_info, flags=re.M)
```

With that, you'll get `[('MyException', "Here's some specific info about my code hitting a problem"), ('Exception', 'The library code hit a problem')]` in `exception_list`

Although this is the easiest way out, it's not very context aware. I mean, all you get are class names in string form. Regardless, if that is what suits your needs - I don't particularly see a problem with this.

### The "robust" approach - recursing through `__context__`/`__cause__`

Python itself keeps track of the exception trace history, the exception currently at hand, the exception that caused this exception and so on. You can read about the intricate details of this concept in [PEP 3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/)

Whether or not you go through the entirety of the PEP, I urge you to at least familiarize yourself with **implicitly chained exceptions** and **explicitly chained exceptions**. Perhaps [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414744/python-exception-chaining) will be useful for that.

As a small refresher, `raise ... from` is for *explicitly chaining* exceptions. The method you show in your example, is *implicit chaining*

Now, you need to make a mental note - [`TracebackException#__cause__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.TracebackException.__cause__) is for **explicitly chained exceptions** and [`TracebackException#__context__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.TracebackException.__context__) is for **implicitly chained exceptions**. Since your example uses implicit chaining, you can simply follow `__context__` backwards and you'll reach `MyException`. In fact, since this is only one level of nesting, you'll reach it instantly!

```py
import sys
import traceback

try:
    library_function(my_callback, 'boo!')
except:
    previous_exc = traceback.TracebackException(*sys.exc_info()).__context__
```

This first constructs the `TracebackException` from [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info). `sys.exc_info` returns a tuple of `(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)` for the exception at hand (if any). Notice that those 3 values, in that specific order, are exactly what you need to construct `TracebackException` - so you can simply destructure it using `*` and pass it to the class constructor.

This returns a `TracebackException` object about the current exception. The exception that it is *implicitly chained from* is in `__context__`, the exception that it is *explicitly chained from* is in `__cause__`.

Note that both `__cause__` and `__context__` will return either a `TracebackException` object, or `None` (if you're at the end of the chain). This means, you can call `__cause__`/`__context__` *again* on the return value and basically keep going till you reach the end of the chain.

Printing a `TracebackException` object just prints the message of the exception, if you want to get the class itself (the actual class, not a string), you can do `.exc_type`

```py
print(previous_exc)
# prints "Here's some specific info about my code hitting a problem."
print(previous_exc.exc_type)
# prints <class '__main__.MyException'>
```

Here's an example of recursing through `.__context__` and printing the types of all exceptions in the implicit chain. (You can do the same for `.__cause__`)

```py
def classes_from_excs(exc: traceback.TracebackException):
    print(exc.exc_type)
    if not exc.__context__:
        # chain exhausted
        return
    classes_from_excs(exc.__context__)
```

Let's use it!

```py
try:
    library_function(my_callback, 'boo!')
except:
    classes_from_excs(traceback.TracebackException(*sys.exc_info()))
```

That will print-

```
<class 'Exception'>
<class '__main__.MyException'>
```

Once again, the point of this is to be context aware. Ideally, printing isn't the thing you'll want to do in a practical environment, you have the class objects themselves on your hands, with all the info!

**NOTE**: For implicitly chained exceptions, if an exception is explicitly suppressed, it'll be a bad day trying to recover the chain - regardless, you might give [`__supressed_context__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.TracebackException.__suppress_context__) a shot.

### The painful way - walking through [`traceback.walk_tb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.walk_tb)

This is probably the closest you can get to the low level stuff of exception handling. If you want to capture entire frames of information instead of just the exception classes and messages and such, you might find `walk_tb` useful....and a bit painful.

```py
import traceback

try:
    library_function(my_callback, 'foo')
except:
    tb_gen = traceback.walk_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

There is....entirely too much to discuss here. `.walk_tb` takes a traceback object, you may remember from the previous method that the 2nd index of the returned tuple from `sys.exec_info` is just that. It then returns a *generator* of tuples of frame object and int (`Iterator[Tuple[FrameType, int]]`).

These frame objects have all kinds of intricate information. Though, whether or not you'll actually find exactly what you're looking for, is another story. They may be complex, but they aren't exhaustive unless you play around with a lot of frame inspection. Regardless, [this is what the frame objects represent](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects).

What you do with the frames is upto you. They can be passed to *many* functions. You can pass the entire generator to [`StackSummary.extract`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.StackSummary.extract) to get framesummary objects, you can iterate through each frame to have a look at `[0].f_locals` (The `[0]` on `Tuple[FrameType, int]` returns the actual frame object) and so on.

```py
for tb in tb_gen:
    print(tb[0].f_locals)
```

That will give you a dict of the [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) for each frame. Within the first `tb` from `tb_gen`, you'll see `MyException` as part of the locals....among a load of other stuff.

I have a creeping feeling I have overlooked some methods, most probably with [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html). But I hope the above methods will be good enough so that no one has to go through the jumble that is `inspect` :P

Comment: Wow! What an *exceptional* writeup, if you'll pardon the pun. I've written a function based on the second approach that works well for now and seems easily extensible for my future needs; I think I will post it as another answer, for completeness's sake. Thank you!

Comment: great answer, I concede ;)

Answer (score 0):

Chase's answer above is phenomenal. For completeness's sake, here's how I implemented their second approach in this situation. First, I made a function that can search the stack for the specified error type. Even though the chaining in my example is implicit, this should be able to follow implicit and/or explicit chaining:

```py
import sys
import traceback

def find_exception_in_trace(exc_type):
    """Return latest exception of exc_type, or None if not present"""
    tb = traceback.TracebackException(*sys.exc_info())
    prev_exc = tb.__context__ or tb.__cause__
    
    while prev_exc:
        if prev_exc.exc_type == exc_type:
            return prev_exc
        prev_exc = prev_exc.__context__ or prev_exc.__cause__
    
    return None
```

With that, it's as simple as:

```py
while True:
    something = input('Enter something: ')
    try:
        library_function(my_callback, something)
    except LibraryException as exc:
        if (my_exc := find_exception_in_trace(MyException)):
            print(my_exc)
            continue
        raise exc
```

That way I can access my inner exception (and print it for now, although eventually I may do other things with it) and continue. But if my exception wasn't in there, I simply reraise whatever the library raised. Perfect!