# Finding out an exception context

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7

tlndr: how to tell in a function if it's called from an `except` block (directly/indirectly). python2.7/cpython.

I use python 2.7 and try to provide something similar to py3's `__context__` for my custom exception class:

```
class MyErr(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Exception.__init__(self, *args)
        self.context = sys.exc_info()[1]
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.args) + ' from ' + repr(self.context)
```

This seems to work fine:

```
try:
   1/0
except:
   raise MyErr('bang!')

#>__main__.MyErr: ('bang!',) from ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',)
```

Sometimes I need `MyErr` to be raised outside of an exception block. This is fine too:

```
raise MyErr('just so')

#>__main__.MyErr: ('just so',) from None
```

If, however, there has been a handled exception before this point, it's being incorrectly set as a context of `MyErr`:

```
try:
    print xxx
except Exception as e:
    pass

# ...1000 lines of code....
raise MyErr('look out')

#>__main__.MyErr: ('look out',) from NameError("name 'xxx' is not defined",) <-- BAD
```

I guess the reason is that  [`sys.exc_info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) simply returns the "last" and not the "current" exception:

> This function returns a tuple of three values that give information about the exception that is currently being handled. <...> Here, “handling an exception” is defined as “executing or **having executed** an except clause.”

So, my question is: how to tell if the interpreter *is* executing an `except` clause (and not *has* it executed in the past). In other words: is there a way to know in `MyErr.__init__` if there is an `except` up on the stack?

My app is not portable, any Cpython specific hacks are welcome.

Comment: This works fine for me. My output is only "#>__main__.MyErr: ('look out',)". sys.exc_info doesn't return the last exception. It returns the exception currently being handled. It returns (None, None, None) when called outside an except block.

Comment: @shshank: are you using python 2.7?

Comment: Python 2.7.4. need to write longer comment

Comment: @shshank: are you sure? I've tested all 2.7.x - the same thing. http://ideone.com/rthInF

Comment: Oh hah! It happens if you run it in a file but not from the IDLE REPL, of course.

Comment: Are you looking for a syntactical approach or a semantic one? e.g. in [this paste](http://pastebin.com/Pd4hGSWb), what do you want the result to be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is tested with CPython 2.7.3:

```
$ python myerr.py 
MyErr('bang!',) from ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',)
MyErr('nobang!',)
```

It works as long as the magic exception is directly created within the scope of an except clause. A little additional code can lift that restriction, though.

```
import sys
import opcode

SETUP_EXCEPT = opcode.opmap["SETUP_EXCEPT"]
SETUP_FINALLY = opcode.opmap["SETUP_FINALLY"]
END_FINALLY = opcode.opmap["END_FINALLY"]

def try_blocks(co):
    """Generate code positions for try/except/end-of-block."""
    stack = []
    code = co.co_code
    n = len(code)
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        op = ord(code[i])
        if op in (SETUP_EXCEPT, SETUP_FINALLY):
            stack.append((i, i + ord(code[i+1]) + ord(code[i+2])*256))
        elif op == END_FINALLY:
            yield stack.pop() + (i,)
        i += 3 if op >= opcode.HAVE_ARGUMENT else 1

class MyErr(Exception):
    """Magic exception."""

    def __init__(self, *args):
        callee = sys._getframe(1)
        try:
            in_except = any(i[1] <= callee.f_lasti < i[2] for i in try_blocks(callee.f_code))
        finally:
            callee = None

        Exception.__init__(self, *args)
        self.cause = sys.exc_info()[1] if in_except else None

    def __str__(self):
        return "%r from %r" % (self, self.cause) if self.cause else repr(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        try:
            1/0
        except:
            x = MyErr('bang!')
            raise x
    except Exception as exc:
        print exc

    try:
        raise MyErr('nobang!')
    except Exception as exc:
        print exc
    finally:
        pass
```

And remember, “Explicit is better than implicit,” so this would be way better if you ask me:

```
try:
    …
except Exception as exc:
    raise MyErr("msg", cause=exc)
```

Comment: This passes even the hardest testcases I could think of: Well done! http://pastebin.com/HHY7BVqx

Comment: If used in production, memoizing `try_blocks` using a hash of `code` as the key would make a lot of sense.

Comment: props for actually implementing this! ended up being simpler than i thought it would be

Answer (score 3):

The following approach might work, although it's a bit long-winded.

- Get the code of the current frame from `import inspect; inspect.currentframe().f_code`
- Inspect the bytecode (`f_code.co_code`), perhaps using `dis.dis`, to figure out whether the frame is being executed in an `except` block.
- Depending on what you want to do, you might want to go back a frame and see if it wasn't called from an except block.

Ex:

```
def infoo():
    raise MyErr("from foo in except")

try:
    nope
except:
    infoo()
```

- If none of the frames are in an `except` block then the `sys.exc_info()` is outdated.

Comment: Yes, this is what I've ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to call [`sys.exc_clear()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) after an exception has been handled:

```
import sys

class MyErr(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Exception.__init__(self, *args)
        self.context = sys.exc_info()[1]
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.args) + ' from ' + repr(self.context)

try:
    print xxx
except Exception as e:
    # exception handled
    sys.exc_clear()

raise MyErr('look out')
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise MyErr('look out')`
__main__.MyErr: ('look out',) from None
```

If there is not many places that handle an exception without raising `MyErr` then it might be more suitable then modifying calls to `MyErr` providing some constructor argument, or even explicitly handling traceback preservation as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350671/inner-exception-with-traceback-in-python/1350981#1350981).

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an option. There are lots of `excepts` without raising MyError, some of them in external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I searched through the Python source to see if there was some indicator that was being set when the entering an `except` block that could be queried by going through the frame sequence from the custom exception's constructor.

I found this [`fblocktype`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/237284d0a73e472f836adc72f090432ae7c5dfad/Python/compile.c#L86) enum that is stored in a `fblockinfo` struct :

```
enum fblocktype { LOOP, EXCEPT, FINALLY_TRY, FINALLY_END };

struct fblockinfo {
    enum fblocktype fb_type;
    basicblock *fb_block;
};
```

There is a comment above the `fblocktype` that describes a **frame block** :

> A frame block is used to handle loops, try/except, and try/finally.
>   It's called a frame block to distinguish it from a basic block in the
>   compiler IR.

And then when you go up a bit there is a description of a **basic block** :

> Each basicblock in a compilation unit is linked via b_list in the
>   reverse order that the block are allocated.  b_list points to the next
>   block, not to be confused with b_next, which is next by control flow.

Also reading some more here about about the [Control Flow Graphs](http://docs.python.org/devguide/compiler.html#control-flow-graphs) :

> A control flow graph (often referenced by its acronym, CFG) is a
>   directed graph that models the flow of a program using basic blocks
>   that contain the intermediate representation (abbreviated “IR”, and in
>   this case is Python bytecode) within the blocks. Basic blocks
>   themselves are a block of IR that has a single entry point but
>   possibly multiple exit points. The single entry point is the key to
>   basic blocks; it all has to do with jumps. An entry point is the
>   target of something that changes control flow (such as a function call
>   or a jump) while exit points are instructions that would change the
>   flow of the program (such as jumps and ‘return’ statements). What this
>   means is that a basic block is a chunk of code that starts at the
>   entry point and runs to an exit point or the end of the block.

So all this seem to indicate that a **frame block** in Python's design is treated as a temporary object. It is not directly included in the *Control Flow Graph* except as part of the encompassing basic block's byte code, so it seems it can not be queried without parsing the frames byte code.

Further, I think the reason in your example the [`sys.exc_info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) is showing the exception from the `try` block is because it stores the last exception of the current **basic block**, frame blocks are not considered here.

> **sys.exc_info()**
>
> This function returns a tuple of three values that give information
>   about the exception that is currently being handled. The information
>   returned is specific both to the current thread and to the current
>   stack frame. If the current stack frame is not handling an exception,
>   the information is taken from the calling stack frame, or its caller,
>   and so on until a stack frame is found that is handling an exception.
>   Here, “handling an exception” is defined as “executing or having
>   executed an except clause.” For any stack frame, only information
>   about the most recently handled exception is accessible.

So when it says *stack frame* there I think it specifically means **basic block** and all the "handling an exception" talk means that exceptions in a **frame block** such as a `try/except`, `for`, and etc. bubble up to the **basic block** above.