# raise *error doesn't work in Python 2.7; how can I raise a previously captured exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, exception

My code works, but I am thinking there is something wrong with my understanding, or possibly (gasp) an error in Python's `raise` behavior.

I am looping over a set of arguments.  I capture the *first* error and want to raise it after I have finished looping, with the original traceback etc as described in [“Inner exception” (with traceback) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350671/inner-exception-with-traceback-in-python)

I obviously want the loop to process all the arguments, and only then tell me what went wrong.

```
error = None
for arg in arguments:
    try:
        process(arg)
    except ValueError, err:
        if not error:
            error = sys.exc_info()
if error:
    raise error[0], error[1], error[2]
```

The last line is the problematic line.  It works (demo: http://ideone.com/HFZETm -- note how it prints the traceback from the first error, not the last one), but it seems extremely clunky.  How could I express that more succinctly?

`raise error` would seem more elegant, but it behaves as if I had simply `raise error[0]` (or perhaps raise `error[1]`).  `raise *error` is a syntax error.

Comment: In Python3, you can do `raise error[1].with_traceback(error[2])`. I don't know of an equivalent for Python 2, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you could just do this:

```
for arg in arguments:
    try:
        process(arg)
    except ValueError:
        raise
```

Also, if you're going to do this multiple times, you could just wrap it in a function:

```
def raise_error(err):
    raise err[0], err[1]. err[2]

error = None
for arg in arguments:
    try:
        process(arg)
    except ValueError, err:
        if not error:
            error = sys.exc_info()
if error:
    raise_error(error)
```

Comment: Huh? No, that would be the same as omitting the `try`/`except` and would cause processing to terminate at the first error.  Clarified the question to emphasize that this is not acceptable.

Comment: Julien, do you really need *two separate* answers to the same question? And they're even so similar... And one starts with "maybe, you could do this", the other "probably not what you're after". I suggest editing them into the same answer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think that they are fundamentally different solutions but I don't mind regrouping them.

Comment: Copying my comment here from the deleted answer; I'm hoping for a way to pass the full argument list to `raise`. Your `raise_error` function is a good workaround for encapsulating away the ugliness, but it's still there inside the `def`; since my code only needs to do this once, the encapsulation doesn't really buy me anything.