# What's the proper way to reraise a custom exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have the function,

```
def parse_datetime(s, **kwargs):
    """ Converts a time-string into a valid
    :py:class:`~datetime.datetime.DateTime` object.

        Args:
            s (str): string to be formatted.

        ``**kwargs`` is passed directly to :func:`.dateutil_parser`.

        Returns:
            :py:class:`~datetime.datetime.DateTime`
    """
    if not s:
        return None
    try:
        ret = dateutil_parser(s, **kwargs)
    except (OverflowError, TypeError, ValueError) as e:
        logger.exception(e, exc_info=True)
        raise SyncthingError(*e.args)
    return ret
```

What's the most correct way to raise the caught exception as the common library exception? (`SyncthingError(Exception)` ) The way it's written right now **does not work correctly**.

Comment: If you want to raise `SyncthingError` then just do: `raise SyncthingError(e)`. If you want to raise the exception you caught, just do `raise`

Comment: Can you try [`raise ... from ...`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#explicit-exception-chaining)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 the exceptions can be chained,

```
raise SyncthingError("parsing error") from e
```

will produce a stack trace with details of the original exception.

There are examples in the [raise statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) docs.

Comment: Is there a Python2 fallback? This is very elegant.

Comment: @blakev there's a compatibility-layer implementation from [`six`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.raise_from) In Python 2 this doesn't do much, but it prevents `SyntaxError`. There's also the `reraise()` function worth looking into.

Comment: @blakev I have started learning Python from version 3. I had to search and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350671/inner-exception-with-traceback-in-python Very similar to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to raise it as long as constructer of the common library exception takes Error or Exception. For example:

```
Class LibraryException(Exception)...
Class LibraryException(Error)...
```