Except Hook not working correctly with Vscode debugger
I'm trying to make a library for python and I want to add custom exceptions, but every time I raise an exception, the exception shows my raise as the problem.
For example:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\james\Desktop\mylibrary\testing.py", line 16, in <module>  
    'the library user doing absolute shit'
  File "c:\Users\james\Desktop\mylibrary\mylibrary\__init__.py", line 100, in function_name
    else: raise errors.myerror('Text about my custom error')  
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
errors.myerror: Text about my custom error

I manage to solve this problem using sys.excepthook and no VSCode debugger (Run Without Debugging):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\james\Desktop\mylibrary\testing.py", line 16, in <module>  
    'the library user doing absolute shit'
errors.myerror: Text about my custom error

But when i use the VSCode debugging tool (Start Debugging) it say again that the problem come from my raise.

Just to make sure, is errors.myerror a class? Could you possibly show code for what you pass to it and code for errors.myerror?

@keventhen4
Yes, it is a class :
class errors:
class myerror(Exception):
def init(self, message):
super().init(message)
self.message = message

It seems the issue is because you are not handling your custom exception correctly. You have not provided your code to raise the error, but here's what a custom exception needs:

Of course the exception class, which you have.
Error raising must happen in a try statement. The code itself can be in a function, but when the code is run it must be happening inside of a try block.
Must have an except statement to handle the error. This is required with any try block and if you don't handle your error correctly, there's no point in having a custom exception.

Here's an example of a custom exception (here's a guide/example on custom exceptions).
class errors:
    class cost_error(Exception):
        def __init__(self, message):
            super().__init__(message)
            self.message = message

money, cost_of_item = 5, 100 #variables for example

try:
    if cost_of_item > money:
        raise errors.cost_error("This item is too expensive!")
    else:
        print("Item purchased!")
except errors.cost_error as error:
    print(f"Error: {error}")
    quit() #This built-in function will terminate the program

print("Hey, if the item is too expensive then this won't print")

As you can see, the error raising happens inside of a try except block. This is because when an error is raised, if it is not inside of a try block it will return your raise statement as an error. If you don't put it into a try block, it will not be handled and will cause your program to stop.
Example error raised when not using try block:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/person/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise errors.cost_error("This item is too expensive!")
__main__.cost_error: This item is too expensive!

However, if you just just put it in a try block but don't handle it, then it'll just ignore the error because that's how the try except block's behavior works. Because of this, you need to handle errors.myerror as an exception in the try block.

I tested your solution, but I encountered a problem. When printing the error, it doesn't display the traceback, which is not ideal. Additionally, because we use quit() to exit the program, when debugging in VSCode, it doesn't show where the error originates.

Hey @James ! If you are trying to get traceback, then what you had before was right. As you can see from your error, it was caused by your line to raise the error. It is the reason for the error because it raised the error. The error gives you the line which raised the error (so if you have multiple error raises, you know which one it was and can trace the origin), and errors.myerror: Text about my custom error basically means that the error was of type errors.myerror and the error message was the message you wanted.
This is how it should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6246394/16169432
